# I am using Spark-Scala from local machine. Spark version 3.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am using Spark-Scala from local machine. Spark version 3.0.1. I need to read data from S3 bucket publicly open from IntelliJ IDEA. Below is my code

```
package AWS

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object Read extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[3]")
    .appName("Accessing AWS S3")
    .getOrCreate()


//  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
//  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
//  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")

  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "XXXXXXXXX")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")

  val dept_df = spark.read.format("csv").load("s3a://hr-data-lake/departments.csv")
  dept_df.printSchema()
  dept_df.show(truncate = false)
}
//s3://hr-data-lake/departments.csv
//sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "XXXXXXXXX")
//sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

//spark.sparkContext.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
//sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

**Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found**

Comment: Can you provide which S3plugin jar you have used?

Comment: spark scala config
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")

  // Reading data from s3 SBT dependency
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.8.3",

Comment: Hi
The problem is solved, needed to pass
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.8.4" in sbt.build